# Whats a good practice to handle localised messages in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, localization

What is a good practice on handling localised messages in Laravel?

For example; 'You have successfully added the user'.

Should I redirect the user to a page which is like `/user/success` or would it be better to do something like `/user?message=success`.

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: Instead of putting the message in the uri, I would put the message into flash memory then display it to the user after a redirect to wherever you want it to display.

Comment: this is really opinion based ... I prefer the first approach, I find it cleaner Url.

Comment: @Jeemusu Would you like to add your answer through with a source? I would love to give you best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer flash message, then on the view you can even get a timeout for the message to make it look really good. Now this approach works for me.
On controller side :

```
if($result==1)
        {
            Session::flash('message', 'You have successfully added the user');
            return Redirect::to('/user/success');
        }
        else{
            Session::flash('message', 'Something went wrong.');
            return Redirect::to('/user/error');
        }
```

Now at view side its simple.

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-info" id="hider">
        {{ Session::get('message') }}   
    </div>
@endif
```

Now you can use jquery or noty to display and auto-hide the message block

Answer (score 1):

Redirect user to `/page/success` with the message `You have successfully added the user` or anything else is more flexible. Example, if the user successful add item to cart, it will also redirect to `/page/success` with another message (just the different message, not the action).